# Is there a way to apply a template variable restriction to a dashboard without showing it as a drop down option?

Tags: datadog-dashboard

There are variables I want to filter on, however I don't want them to be able to be changed or unchecked. in fact, my boss doesn't want them to be seen at all. is there a way to accomplish this?

I have listed a default option as well as limited the available values. this still allows for the unchecking of the variable however. I want to set the restrictions as a property of the dashboard itself